# How to launch event from custom component

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have created a custom component which inherits class textBox.

```
Public Class MyTextBox
    Inherits TextBox

    Sub MyLeave() Handles MyBase.Leave
        Me.BackColor = Color.Red
    End Sub

End Class
```

If I leave the textbox it becomes red, but I can't trigger this from my code.
What can I do to launch the `Leave` event from my code? I want to call the `Leave` event implemented in my component **without** calling  `MyTextBox1.MyLeave()`.

Do I have to create a custom event?

Comment: An event is something that happens when the action took place. In this case when the TextBox lost focus, either because the user has tabbed out of it or clicked elsewhere on the Form. You can't and you should not trigger it programmatically. Instead you should implement a method, for exampe `ApplyColor` which you can call whenever you like. Then you can call this method from `MyLeave` and from outside(if it's public).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some combat it seems: You Can't.

The closest I got was the error "Derived classes cannot raise base class events."  which tells me that what I'm trying to do is doomed to fail.

So! We shall overcome. Make a new sub called RedifyButton and have the handler call that, passing the sender param. Then your 2nd method can also call RedifyButton instead of simulating a UI event.

I know deep down 'there must be a way' but it seems there isn't.